# How to run bat file with required permissions in C#

Tags: c#, process, permissions, batch-file

I have a bat file that copies files from one location to another.

```
SET SRC=%1
SET DEST=%2

xcopy /Y/I %SRC%\*.txt %DEST%\temp
echo Done!
```

I'm trying to run this file via C# program

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(fileToRun);
psi.Arguments = args;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process cmdProc = Process.Start(psi); 

StreamReader output = cmdProc.StandardOutput;
StreamReader errors = cmdProc.StandardError;
cmdProc.WaitForExit();
```

Bat-file is executed, I can see the **'Done!'** message in the output, but files are not copied.

The only way it works is

```
psi.UseShellExecute = true;

psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
psi.RedirectStandardError = false;
```

But in this case I have to disable output/error redirection and I need them.
So this doesn't work for me.

I have tried to set administrator's username/password

```
psi.UserName = username;
psi.Password = password;
```

Logon succeed, but I get the **'The handle is invalid'** message in the StandardError Stream.

I guess the process I'm trying to run doesn't have permissions to copy files and
I don't know how to grant him these permissions.

Please, help!

**EDITED**

Thank you for replies! 
I have spend several hours trying to handle this issue and as it always happens I have posted my question and found the solution :)

In order to avoid getting 'The handle is invalid' message you have to

```
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```

***But now I can see cmd.exe window, if UserName is set, which is bad.***

Comment: In case where you capture the output of `XCOPY` what does it say? It should include `Access denied` (or your language's equivalent) if permissions are the issue.

Comment: It said nothing, failed silently, no errors in standard error stream.

Comment: Temporarly put an `ECHO` infront of the `XCOPY`. Does the ouptut show the command line (source/target directories, etc.) you expect?

Comment: Also, what exactly is in `args` and `fileToRun` when the failure happens?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have found the solution, but now I have another problem - I can see cmd.exe window even though psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

Comment: Similar question with same solution and more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910592/process-waitforexit-on-console-vs-windows-forms

Comment: to understand : you want to start a batch file with a specific user account , while the batch file runs it shouldn't ask / wait for username and whatever supplied via c# just use that , correct ?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing

```
psi.Domain = "domain";
psi.Verb ="runas";
//if you are using local user account then you need supply your machine name for domain
```

try this simple snippet should work for you

```
void Main()
{
    string batchFilePathName =@"drive:\folder\filename.bat";
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(batchFilePathName);

    psi.Arguments = "arg1 arg2";//if any
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.Verb ="runas";
    psi.UserName = "UserName"; //domain\username
    psi.Domain = "domain"; //domain\username
    //if you are using local user account then you need supply your machine name for domain

    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.Verb ="runas";

    Process ps = new Process(psi);
    Process.Start(ps);  
}
```

Comment: this might come handy if you run across any windows UAC issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7